# Append values to property in sass mixin

Tags: sass

I have the following sass mixin:

```
@mixin absoluteCenterVertical {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

I want to be able to pass additional transform properties to my mixin so I can use it like

```
.element {
  @include absoluteCenterVertical(rotate(45deg))
}
```

which will compile into

```
.element {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[arguments](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#arguments)** with mixins.

```
@mixin absoluteCenterVertical($extraTransformVals:) {
  transform: translateY(-50%) $extraTransformVals;
}
```

However, the above will require always passing an argument with `@include absoluteCenterVertical(rotate(90));` or whatever you may pass. If you don't pass an argument, sass will give an error during compilation.

If you want to have an **[optional argument](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#optional-arguments)** so that the mixin works without passing an argument like `@include absoluteCenterVertical;`, you have to provide a default value using the syntax `@mixin mixinName($argName: $defaultArgValue)`

Here's one way you can do it:

```
@mixin absoluteCenterVertical($extraTransformVals: noExtraValues) {
  @if $extraTransformVals == noExtraValues {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  } @else {
    transform: translateY(-50%) $extraTransformVals;
  }
}
```